# Control variable with slider

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to control the variable length with a range slider, such that the slider can be able to increase or reduce length of the line.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var length = 450

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(length, 100);
context.stroke();
   
   
slider.addEventListener("change", function() { 
   length = slider.value;  
})

setInterval(function() {
  length = slider.value;
 
}, 100)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="578" step="1" value="50" > 
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what does or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think You do not need the Interval and You should just redraw the line(after cleaning up) inside the event handler function; maybe using the 'input' event is better.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var length = 450

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(length, 100);
context.stroke();


slider.addEventListener("input", function() { 
    length = slider.value; 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100, 100);
    context.lineTo(length, 100);
    context.stroke();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g0ay525v/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to redraw the entire line if you want to make its length change. Here's an example of how it can work :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var length = 450

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(length, 100);
context.stroke();
     
slider.addEventListener("change", function() { 
   length = slider.value;  
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clears the entire canvas
   context.beginPath(); // Draw the line with the new length
   context.moveTo(100, 100);
   context.lineTo(length, 100);
   context.stroke();
})

// You didn't need setIntertval.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>    
  </head>
  <body>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="578" step="1" value="50" > 
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On change event, call a function and pass the value of length to clear the canvas, then redraw the line

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
  length = 450;

// you may add this line to sync the slider with the line before change event happens
slider.value = length; 

reDraw(length);

slider.addEventListener("change", function() {
  length = slider.value;
  reDraw(length);
});

function reDraw(length) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 100);
  context.lineTo(length, 100);
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="578" step="1" value="50">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

---

You can also listen to the **[`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)** event instead of `change` thus you'll update the length of the line *instantly* as you drag the slider, unlike in the case of `change` event where updating the length of the line only happens *after* you release the mouse button.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  slider = document.getElementById("slider"),
  length = 450;

// you may add this line to sync the slider with the line before change event happens
slider.value = length;

reDraw(length);

slider.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  length = slider.value;
  reDraw(length);
});

function reDraw(length) {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(100, 100);
  context.lineTo(length, 100);
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="578" step="1" value="50">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```